# App made in Applescript Icon wont change

Tags: applescript, icon

The app's Icon wont change for me I tried copying in contents as "applet.icns" I tried Copy + Paste in get info nothing will work I found a article on the internet about this problem they say that you need to do -ls -la in Terminal but that wont work for me

Any help appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to Your **Info.plist** file:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>filename</string>
```

where `filename` is Your **.icns** file inside `Contents/Resources` directory. Info form the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102043)

> CFBundleIconFile (String - iOS, OS X) identifies the file containing the icon for the bundle. The filename you specify does not need to include the extension, although it may. The system looks for the icon file in the main resources directory of the bundle.
>
> If your Mac app uses a custom icon, you must specify this property. If you do not specify this property, the system (and other apps) display your bundle with a default icon.