# AppleScript icon (ICNS) not changing

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, applescript, high-sierra

i create a little app using Script Editor and exported to .app file. now im trying to change the icon to a custom .icns file. the icns file was converted from a png using [this website](https://findicons.com/convert). also tried using [this website](https://cloudconvert.com/png-to-icns).

after copying the icns to `Contents/Resources/applet.icns` and modifying the below lines of the Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>applet</string>
```

also tried `Contents/Resources/customFilename.icns` and `Contents/Resources/customFilename`:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>customFilename</string>
```

the .app icon doesnt change. im sure the files are in .icns format. how can i debug and figure out why the .app isnt taking the .icns's?

[App made in Applescript Icon wont change](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225384/app-made-in-applescript-icon-wont-change?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No image conversion was necessary.  In Finder.app, just (control + click) on the file that you want to change its icon, and choose the "Get  info" command.  Next, just drag your icon file from Finder, directly onto the actual icon image in the get info window you previously opened... Then you're good to go

[image]

Comment: yeah i feel pretty stupid. thanks for your help. maybe you can help with this? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325206/why-do-icns-files-need-to-be-perfect-squares

Comment: I tried a few different solutions, and this is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The [solution provided by wch1zpink](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/325201/436803) seems to work well, but it does not change the icon stored inside the bundle. Already zipping and unzipping the bundle or copying to a smb-share reverts the icon to its standard as it is defined in *info.plist*. (Strangely, copying it via vnc to another machine does not affect the icon)

Therefore i **suppose**, that the icon-change is stored in some *DS_Store*-file or *Spotlight* Database: as long as Apple has full control over it, it keeps the icon; as soon as you leave the apple-universe the icon change is lost. If you want to deploy the script with the modified icon this is not recommended.

I recommend to overwrite the icon file. Rename your customized icns file, so that it has the same name as the one already within the app-bundle, then replace it.

Note: if you use Automator to create your apps, it will overwrite the icon every time you save it, therefore keep a backup of your custom-icns.