# Why do ICNS files need to be perfect squares?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, applescript, icon

im able to [modify .app icons](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325196/applescript-icon-icns-not-changing) only when the dimensions are perfectly even (eg. 256x256) but not rectangular shapes.

[this website](https://findicons.com/convert) allows for exporting png images as icns files in any dimension but they dont seem to work with .app's?

**is it possible to modify an app to use a rectangular .icns?**

Comment: While the overall dimensions need be square, i.e. 16×16, 32×32, 64×64, 128×128, 256×256, 512×512, or 1024×1024, nonetheless you can create an icon where the visible part is not square and or can be any shape and size you want smaller then the aforementioned dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible. macOS only supports square icons for this purpose.

The size must be either 16 × 16, 32 × 32, 48 × 48, 128 × 128, 256 × 256, 512 × 512, or 1024 × 1024.

Note that even though the physical dimensions of the icons must be square, it is possible to create the illusion of having a non-square icon by making parts of the icon transparent.

Comment: I do not believe `48 × 48` is as standard size but `64×64` is. At least according to [Create Your Own Custom Icons in OS X 10.7.5 or Later](https://blog.macsales.com/28492-create-your-own-custom-icons-in-10-7-5-or-later). That said though, I'd have to check the sizes that Xcode uses to create and icon.

Comment: It is a "standard size" and is supported. The reason is that Windows icons used to be 48x48. However, 48x48 is not a recommended size if you're creating new icons for macOS. Refer to the HIG then.

Answer (score -1):

Contrary to @jksoegaard the method in the below video seems to work. He seems to be using a non-square shaped image and modifies the applet.icns *before* exporting it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6d44xD6f4c

Comment: If you paid closer attention to the video at the point he created the icon using the website service, while the cropped image he dropped was rectangular, nonetheless the .icns file created is indeed square and corresponds to what I said to the OP in a comment. What @ksoegaard said is true as far as over all dimensions, however note what I said in my comment to the OP.